# CPLEX Studio V20.10 fails to open on mac os

Tags: macos, cplex, ilog

I downloaded the IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio V20.10 for OSX (CC8AVML ) version from the IBM website. I installed it on my MAC, no problem seem to occur during installation. When I go to  Applications > CPLEX_Studio201 > opl > oplide I see an oplide app with this image: [image], along with an SDK folder. The app is 8.1MB in size but when I try to open it says: You do not have permission to open the application “Oplide”. The privacy settings have privilege Read & Write but it still does not work. I have tried installing / re-installing a dozen times, restarted my mac, basically tried everything. Can anyone help?

Comment: See https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=46a9fe7e-5e0a-4f86-bc0a-7b63c9235e33&CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7&tab=digestviewer#bm46a9fe7e-5e0a-4f86-bc0a-7b63c9235e33

Answer (score 0):

What version of OSX are you running ? If this is OSX BigSur, the 20.1 installer
does not work on BigSur. We have a beta version for OSX Big Sur.
I'm not entitled to check subscriptions - so I cannot check what version I can send you. Please open a ticket at support asking them to forward message to me and I will send you an installer for OSX BigSur.

If you are not on OSX BigSur, then something went wrong - please include your installation log (in $CPLEX_STUDIO_DIR201/Uninstall/Logs) so that we can have a look.